# Wordpress rest api not found with % in url

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

i try to use the rest api with encrypted data in the url.

For example i create the url with given data like this:

```
$data = (object) [
    'name' => $_POST["name"],
    'email' => $_POST["email"],
    'telefon' => $_POST["telefon"],
    'firma' => $_POST["firma"],
    'timestamp' => "123",
];

$json = json_encode($data);

$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($json, $this->cipher, $this->key);

$url_data = urlencode($encrypted);

$url = site_url() . '/wp-json/ebooks/' . $url_data;
```

My `register_rest_route` looks like this:

```
register_rest_route(
    'ebooks', '/(?P<data>.*)', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => array($this, 'optin'),
    'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
));
```

Example of generated url:

```
http://127.0.0.1//wp-json/ebooks/NgG90Q7hogoX05oildW45kQA2ykAzYBISpkl128IkfeLqqhG3dsbMsPVLCCx9AgvCkOtEM7iOwBlxjY5nidoKiGBKbU3TYYiiKbS85pA9SDrS0wtDA%2FAmHN4CfxpGONm
```

If i open that url i get a 404 error. I think the `%` in the url is the problem. If i replace the `%` with another digit or character than all works fine!

Why is the `%` a problem and how can i solve it?

**Edit:**

My `optin` function.

```
public function optin($data) {
    $dec_url = urldecode($data['data']);
    
    $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($dec_url, $this->cipher, $this->key);

    $json = json_decode($decrypted);

    print_r($json);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`%2F` is the character `/`, URL-encoded by your call to `urlencode()`.  Probably your `optin()` isn't URL-decoding your `data` parameter before it's looking it up, so it's throwing a 404 when it doesn't find the record.

Comment: I decode the data in the `optin` function  with `urldecode` but the code wouldn't reached. Wordpress itself seems to be interpreted the `%` wrong.

Comment: Conceivably Wordpress is URL-decoding it before it reaches the REST router and deciding the `/` is a metacharacter.  Might be worth double-URL-encoding it and seeing what happens.

Comment: If i double urlencode `urlencode(urlencode($encrypted))` the `optin` function would reached. But i can't get the object that i encrypt in my function that generate the url. I have added my code for the `optin` function to my question. The  print_r($json) print nothing.

Comment: If i double `urldecode` in the optin function, it works fine! But why i must call it and the `urlencode` twice?

Comment: @BastiG.: if two `urlencode()`s are happening, then two `urldecode()`s have to happen. i guess you're getting both the explicit one you're doing and an implicit one that WP is imposing on you. which means you could probably just drop your explicit one and be fine.